# If voltage and current are inverse to each other, how do we get higher power?

Tags: power, amperage, ohms-law

I am dazzled; I'm young (teen) so am not too good, but I am wondering if current is proportional to voltage, how do we get high power?

What I'm trying to say is that if we were to have a 5 V supply, from a battery or lab bench power supply, how do we make it like 10 A?

Comment: In cases where they are inverse to each other, you can still get more power by raising the voltage or lowering the resistance. Either one will raise the power.

Comment: Your question title is unclear, and you need to clarify what do you mean by "voltage and current inverse to each other", where did you get that from, which part of which text (if you know or remember, which formula, stuff like that.
Then you state in your first sentence that current is proportional to voltage, which sort of contradicts the statement in the title.
 Finally, you need to be more clear about the example you're providing. Feel free to give a longer and more detailed explanation so that we know exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> if current is proportional to voltage, …

This is the case for *resistors* (or more generally *resistive loads* like incandescent light bulbs, toasters etc).

There's other kinds of loads, too, where the development of voltage over time matters (like for capacitors or inductors), or where the current-per-voltage dependency is not *proportional*, but exponential (like in a diode), but that's stuff you might learn later.

**Important** here is that the load defines this relationship: You apply a voltage, the load defines how much current flows through it.

> What I'm trying to say is that if we were to have a 5 V supply, from a battery or lab bench power supply, how do we make it like 10 A?

We can't. Physics won't let us adjust current when we have a fixed load and a fixed voltage. If we want more current, we will have to increase the voltage.

Comment: ok, so if we have a bench power supply with a lamp that draws 10kwatts, the amount of current will be higher, and if we wanted to reduce the current were would just use something such as a resistor. Because I already knew about that capacitor and inductor stuff but got confused often, thank you very much

Comment: @Gabrielashmore exactly! Because power \$P=V·I\$, \$V\$ being the voltage (5 V) and \$I\$ being the current, we can directly calculate that in that case, \$I=P/V=10\;000\,\text{W}/(5\,\text{V})= 2000\,\text{A}\$. That is very much. (no bench power supply will be able to even offer that much current, but that's a different problem).

Comment: Yeah, that was an imaginary example, well thanks a lot anyways.

Comment: @Gabrielashmore you're welcome! I guess you know how this site's "answer acceptance" mechanism works. Please don't forget to come back and accept if you think this is the right answer (or don't, if you don't :) ).

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've seen rack-mount supplies that can provide that much current. And one of my coworkers insists on using a rack-mount supply just sitting on the benchtop, so you *could* call that a bench power supply.

Answer (score 1):

Seemingly you know terms voltage and current but you do not know what physical things they actually measure and what creates relations between voltage and current.

You seem to think that there's a property X (which has name voltage) in your battery or power supply and that X is now say 5V. Now you ask how to change that exactly same X to 10 amperes - X is no more 5V, it must be changed to 10A. That's unfortunately nonsense. A physical quantity cannot be changed to another. A printed label (=ink) could be changed in that way. Hopefully you did not think that way and it was only created in my imagination.

Current flows through wires and conductive materials if there's some voltage connected between the ends of a wire or some other conductive piece of material.

Resistors are common components which are made to have certain easy to predict relation between voltage and current. Resistors obey Ohm's Law (learn it from elementary electricity textbooks)

If you have a 5 volt voltage source you need 0,5 ohms resistor connected between the output poles of the voltage source to get 10A current through the resistor. Current = Voltage divided by Resistance.

That's Ohm's Law and it predicts the current right if the voltage source is not limited in any way, but really keeps the voltage and there's nothing else in the circuit than one resistor + short wires, so short that their resistance is neglible.

10A is too much for small lab power supplies and many batteries. I guess most of them drop their voltage in much lower currents so that Ohm's law alone cannot be used.

There's no way to make those voltage sources to be able to output more current. The only way is to get a bigger one.

Finally: Ohm's Law is not the only law and the most of the electronic components are not resistors at all. Diodes, transistors, capacitors etc... obey other lavs between current and voltage.

Comment: Yep, I knew most of that already but I always got confused with current and thought of it kind of like voltage. getting mixed up in ways that I thought current draw was just like how many amps a component takes from amps that were already there, ok thank you though.

Comment: p.s how do I use the acceptance, anyways thank you though.

Comment: Click the accept button near the top left corner of the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some electronics-related laws such as Kirchhoff's Laws are generally applicable to all kinds of electronic circuits, in the same sense that Newton's laws of motion are generally applicable to all kinds objects.  In both cases, actual real-world behavior won't precisely match the mathematical model, and in some cases may deviate substantially from it, but such deviations may be viewed as resulting from additional phenomena that affect the flow of electrons or an object's movements, but by amounts that are usually small enough to be inconsequential.

Ohm's Law is different, however.  It only applies to objects that behave as passive linear devices, or interconnected combinations of them.  Ohm's Law is useful because it allows someone who can predict how such devices or combinations would behave in isolation to predict how interconnected combinations will behave.

Note that Ohm's Law only has predictive power for passive linear devices, or other devices whose behavior is close to them (the more a device's behavior deviates from that of a passive linear device, the less accurately Ohm's law will predict it).  Many kinds of power conversion devices include components whose behavior is not meaningfully described by Ohm's Law, and thus their overall behavior isn't described by Ohm's Law either.

Answer (score 0):

Your question title and text/body need to be improved, with more text to clarify exactly how you understand voltage, current and power and their relationship, and what exactly do you mean by your question and example.
You are encouraged to add more text to help us understand you better.

Since you seem to understand very little about the basics of voltage and current, I will try to explain in the simplest and shortest terms, using the analogy with water, since the basic electrical characteristics can be easily explained and understood in terms of water:

1. Voltage (in VOLTS) is like a pressure pushing electrons. The higher the voltage, the higher the pressure.
2. Current (in AMPERES or AMPS for short) is the amount/number of electrons passing through a conductor or a device. Compared to water, it is like the amount or volume of water (a.k.a. water flow rate, like litres per second) passing through a pipe or valve in a certain amount of time.
   The higher the voltage/pressure, the more current or more electrons will be pushed through the same device or resistor, just like with water under higher pressure; you will get more water passing through the same-sized pipe.
3. Power (in WATTS) is the combination of the two (voltage and current); multiplying voltage and current will give you the power, similar to combining the water pressure with the amount of water flow. Power is simply the amount of work done in a given amount of time.

I hope that some things are more clear now, so that I can answer your question more directly: If current is proportional to voltage, how do we get high power? (Or, how do we get high current with low voltage, if I understood you correctly?)
It seems that you think that we need higher voltage to achieve higher currents.
Based on the analogy with water, we can achieve high current with low voltage, just like we can achieve high amount of water flow with low water pressure.
The answer is simply by lowering resistance to the current or water flow,
which for electricity means using larger wires and making a device more conductive (allowing more electrons to go through),
while for water it means using larger pipe(s) and opening the valve more, so more water will go through even at the same low pressure.

In summary, the amount of electricity (a.k.a. current) flowing through a wire or device does not depend only on the voltage, but also on the amount of resistance being offered to that flow; the higher the resistance, the lower the flow.
The amount of current is directly proportional to the voltage,
but inversely proportional to the resistance.

(I'm talking here about purely resistive circuits, no need to confuse you with more until you comprehend the basics)

Here is an example:
If you connect a heater with a high resistance of 1000 ohms to a high voltage of 1000 volts, you will get a current of only 1 ampere, which will equal the power of 1000 watts or 1kW (kilo-watt).

I (A) = E (V) / R (ohms)

P (W) = E (V) x I (A)

also P (W) = I² (A) x R (ohms), because P=ExI and E=IxR, so P=(IxR)xI > P=I²R

ON the other hand, if you have a heater whose resistance is only 1 ohm, and a voltage of 50 volts, you will get a current of 50 amperes (amps, for short); multiply the voltage and current, and you get 2500 watts, or 2.5 times more power and 50 times higher current simply because you have much lower resistance.

Read this through, "chew on it" for some time, and it will slowly become more and more clear. You just need to practice these perceptions and calculations, and you will get to fully comprehend it. It takes time for your brain to put everything in its right place, so don't be disappointed if you don't understand everything immediately. Hardly anyone does.